# Fix bug in Siwa

Tags: ubisoft-connect, assassins-creed-origins

I have a problem. I get the following message every time I try to leave Siwa:

> "*This feature isn't installed yet. Please wait for Assassin's Creed Origins to install completely.*"

I can't find out what it is. Do I need to install something, or am I missing a patch?

Comment: What about the message is confusing to you? "This feature isn't installed **yet**. **Please wait** for Assassin's Creed Origins to install completely."

Answer (score 1):

**Assassin's Creed Origins hasn't fully downloaded yet**. Wait for Uplay to download all data, or continue the download of the game, and try again.

It's a feature of Uplay to let you play games *while* downloading, by downloading a playable part of the game first (e.g. putting videos, textures, geometry etc. that will only show up later in the game at the end of the download queue).
Uplay probably showed the message '*Ready to Play*', which is not necessarily the same as 'completely downloaded'.

Comment: Thanks, I  just deleted  it so now I'm installing  it again,

Comment: I think that was quite unnecessary. It should just continue downloading. Just remember to not stop or pause the download once the game is 'Ready to Play'. It still needs more data.